# When an value in an array is 0 it turns into -

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [played] => 2
    [random] => 0
    [win] => 2
    [draws] => 11
    [passes] => 2
    [swaps] => 6
    [hpoints] => 0
    [lpoints] => -12
    [hmoves] => 11
    [lmoves] => 0
    [hpasses] => 1
    [lpasses] => 0
    [hswaps] => 3
    [lswaps] => 0
    [today] => 2013-04-04
    [tdpoints_temp] => -24
    [tdpoints] => -24
    [htdpoints] => 0
    [ltdpoints] => -12
)
```

I then get the array out into seperate values like this:

```
foreach($userStats as $singleStat){
    $played = $singleStat['played'];
    $random = $singleStat['random'];
    $win = $singleStat['win'];
    $draws = $singleStat['draws'];
    $passes = $singleStat['passes'];
    $swaps = $singleStat['swaps'];
    $hpoints = $singleStat['hpoints'];
    $lpoints = $singleStat['lpoints'];
    $hmoves = $singleStat['hmoves'];
    $lmoves = $singleStat['lmoves'];
    $hpasses = $singleStat['hpasses'];
    $lpasses = $singleStat['lpasses'];
    $hswaps = $singleStat['hswaps'];
    $lswaps = $singleStat['lswaps'];
    $today = $singleStat['today'];
    $tdpoints_temp = $singleStat['tdpoints_temp']-$playeridPoints;
    $tdpoints = $singleStat['tdpoints']-$playeridPoints;
    $htdpoints = $singleStat['htdpoints'];
    $ltdpoints = $singleStat['ltdpoints'];
}
```

No problem except. All the variables ($random, $hpoints, $lmoves, $lpasses, $lswaps and $htdpoints) which are "0" comes out as "-" when I echo them? I can't figure out why, and I want them to return "0" as they should.

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance :-)

//########### EDIT #############//

Here is the full code:

```
if($cacheAvailable == true){ // WE GOT A CACHE
    //$memcache->delete('stats_'.$opponent);
    $userStats = $memcache->get('stats_'.$opponent);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($userStats);
    echo '</pre>';

    foreach($userStats as $singleStat){
        $played = $singleStat['played'];
        $random = $singleStat['random'];
        $win = $singleStat['win'];
        $draws = $singleStat['draws'];
        $passes = $singleStat['passes'];
        $swaps = $singleStat['swaps'];
        $hpoints = $singleStat['hpoints'];
        $lpoints = $singleStat['lpoints'];
        $hmoves = $singleStat['hmoves'];
        $lmoves = $singleStat['lmoves'];
        $hpasses = $singleStat['hpasses'];
        $lpasses = $singleStat['lpasses'];
        $hswaps = $singleStat['hswaps'];
        $lswaps = (int)$singleStat['lswaps']; 
        $today = $singleStat['today'];
        $tdpoints_temp = $singleStat['tdpoints_temp']-$playeridPoints;
        $tdpoints = $singleStat['tdpoints']-$playeridPoints;
        $htdpoints = $singleStat['htdpoints'];
        $ltdpoints = $singleStat['ltdpoints'];
    }
    echo 'This swap: '.$lswaps.'<br><br>';
}
```

Comment: There must be some code which is doing that. It can't be done automatically. Can you show us exactly where you are echoing it ?

Comment: I guess that's not the entire foreach, what else do you do inside it?

Comment: I think the evil code wizard is tricking you...

Comment: Try to use extract: http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: What does your `$userStats` array look like?

Comment: Nothing is wrong in your code,I think that data will be changed some where else.Can you show the code between array creation and your foreach loop??

Comment: You can print_r($singleStat) before set variable and see what is real data in array.

Comment: I have edited my original post with the full code. (int) does the trick but it is still weird though!?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0 cantbe converted to '-' there must be some conversions made by you

try to use typecasting

```
$played = (int)$singleStat['played'];
$random = (int)$singleStat['random'];
```